# Where to Get Encryption Key for Realm App in Swift

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-browser

I have a Swift app that uses the Realm Object Server running remotely on a Linux server. Everything is working, including real-time sync.

Occasionally I want to inspect the contents of a local Realm file used by the iOS Simulator so I can do some debugging. When I browse here:

```
~/.../CoreSimulator/.../Documents/realm-object-server/<unique id>/
```

...and I try to open this file: `realm%3A%2F%2F104%2E236%2E129%2E235%3A9080%2F%7E%2Fmyapp.realm`

I get prompted with: **Please enter a valid encryption key for this Realm file.**
[image]
Where do I get this encryption key? I tried using the admin token from the server, but that doesn't appear to be working.

Also, can I turn off encryption everywhere? Or is it mandatory for any app using the Realm Object Server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to open the local version of a synced Realm file using the Browser (or anything else, for that matter). This is due to differing history types internally (but I won't go into that now). In order to inspect the contents of the Realm file, you have to open it using the previously defined `syncURL`. The browser will then download the file and show you the contents.

A few links on this topic:

- https://github.com/realm/RealmTasks/issues/327
- https://github.com/realm/realm-core/issues/2276

Answer (score 1):

You may use old version of `Realm Browser`, please update it and check the result again.

Comment: https://github.com/realm/realm-studio/releases

Answer (score 0):

Use `Realm Studio` instead which worked for me.

[Here can download the file](https://realm.io/cn/products/realm-studio/)

Comment: Up to date versions of Realm Studio here: https://github.com/realm/realm-studio

Answer (score -2):

```
byte[] key = new byte[64]; 
new SecureRandom().nextBytes(key); 
String encryptionKey = byteArrayToHexString(key); 
//encryptionKey is what you want byteArrayToHexString see
Log.d("test", "encryptionKey:"+encryptionKey);
```

byteArrayToHexString() method you can see:[How to convert a byte array to a hex string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java)

Comment: Hi, could you please expand a little on this? Do you have a source, for example?

Comment: byte[] key = new byte[64];
new SecureRandom().nextBytes(key); 
String encryptionKey = byteArrayToHexString(key);
Log.d("test","encryptionKey:"+encryptionKey);//encryptionKey is what you want

byteArrayToHexString see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java

Comment: Ok, please [edit] your answer and add it there. Comments are not a great place to add code, as they don't support formatting, and according to the site rules they could be deleted at any time. Thank you!